# Trying to add a code to my CSS but it doesn't work

Tags: css

So I made a small change on the page (gesher-jds.org/giving):

```
<a href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="anchor1">Donate Now, Pay Later</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="payLater">Donate Now, Pay Later</a>
```

and now the design of the right calculator has changed (more like the button as I see). How do I fix it? Both of them looked the same (besides the text). I tried to add the code below to the CSS but it still didn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

CSS

```
a#payLater {
    background: #60426c;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff !important;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to help. Please provide some codepen example because as far as I can see, you've only changes the id atrribute value. Maybe change all occurences of #anchor1 to #payLater in css styles ? (It's not a good practice but it might work)

Comment: The problem is that the left calculator is using the #anchor1, that's why I'm trying to change it. Can't I just add the code below to the CSS file with the same id? When I tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe use class instead ?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: <a href="#myAnchor" rel="" class="payLater">Donate Now, Pay Later</a>
and you style it like .payLater {styles here}

Comment: I still need the id, because it's connected to other things. Can I put the id and class together?

Comment: Technically, you can

Comment: I used this one: <a href="#myAnchor" rel="" class="payLater" id="payLater">Donate Now, Pay Later</a> but it still didn't work.

Comment: And this one: .payLater {
    background: #60426c;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff !important;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none !important;

Comment: Go to the page, open dev tools, click the html element and you'll see his styles on the righ. Copy and paste the styles to the box on the right "element.style".It works correctly and the styling gets applied. The reason it's not working for you is that your styles are probably getting overwritten by other styles. You'll see there which styles are applied

Comment: So what can I do in order to fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

If you apply the styling in the dev tools it works like expected. The reason it does not work in your working environment is probably because your styles are overwritten by different styles. Check the dev tools to see which styles are applied

Potential fixes:
1) Tidy up the "!important" rules.
2) Build stronger selectors -> keyword to look for knowledge [CSS Specificity]
If you set !important in one CSS rule, it'll become hard to overwrite that because !important = 1000 Specificity points so the rule is really strong

Comment: It's weird, but when I add this code to the css, it looks like it cant even find it: a#payLater {
    background: #60426c;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff !important;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    }

Comment: Sorry i couldn't anwer. Did you manage to fix the issue ? I went to the website and it looks good now, is it right ?

Comment: two looking good buttons next to each other. It's the desired look I guess

Comment: I didn't fix it. I just checked. I tried everything and it doesn't work. It looks like #payLater can't find the #payLater in the css file. How do I fix it?

Comment: I just checked and it doesn't look good. I still don't see the button.

Comment: It's really weird because it works for me. I see two buttons with correct styles applied. Try clearing the cache

Comment: I did. I also checked from a different computer.

Comment: It's weird. It looks fine on my phone and edge. When I check on other computers, I don't see the change. Why not?